# why i still can't use the NumPy module even the terminal says "requirement already satisfied"?

Tags: python, numpy

i was using

```
pip install numpy
```

to install NumPy on my Mac. Then the terminal says that

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
```

I guess it means Numpy is already installed?
but when i wrote

```
from numpy import array
a=array([1,3],int)
```

the python shell says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/bamford/Documents/python/untitled-3.py", line 1, in <module>
from numpy import array
builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

what is going on?

Comment: Are you using an IDE? and does your machine have more than one python distribution installed?

Comment: If you have more than one python installed this can easily happen. what does `import sys; print(sys.path)` say?

Comment: are you using `python 3.*` ?

Comment: @unutbu i'm using Wing101

Comment: @Bijoy i'm using Python 3.6

Comment: @StephenRauch it says ['/Users/bamford/Documents/python', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/Users/bamford/Documents/python']

Answer (score 1):

Per [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143533/why-i-still-cant-use-the-numpy-module-even-the-terminal-says-requirement-alrea?noredirect=1#comment83283537_48143533), notice that your `sys.path` includes directories whose names imply they are associated with Python3.6:

> [... '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/**Versions/3.6**/lib/pytho‌​n36.zip', ...]

Yet NumPy has been installed in your Python2.7 distribution:

> Requirement already satisfied: numpy in 
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/**Versions/2.7**/Extras/lib/python

(my emphasis) So your Wing101 IDE is using Python3, and not finding NumPy because NumPy has not (yet) been installed in your Python3 distribution.

One solution would be to install NumPy for your Python3 distribution. (Another, might be to configure Wing101 to run Python2.7.) Often, the `pip` executable associated with Python3 is named `pip3` (to distinguish it from a Python2 version called `pip`.) So you might try

```
pip3 install numpy
```

to install NumPy.

---

Moral of the story: Every pip is associated with a particular Python distribution. `pip` is a Python script. When run, it calls the Python executable associated with that distribution.

To install modules for a particular Python using `pip`, you need to call the `pip` script which is associated with the desired Python executable.

Answer (score 0):

The message pip shows in your system

> Requirement already satisfied: numpy in 
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python

Here as you can note, `numpy` module is installed in `python 2.7`'s directory.
You should install it in `python 3.*`'s directory. You can try that by

`pip3 install numpy`

`pip3` installs python libraries in `python 3.*`directory

add `sudo` at the beginning of command to install it system wide.