# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlrd'

Tags: python

I am completely new here. This is my first post, however I have been an SO member for a couple months, reading questions and answers. I need help figuring out how to import an xlsx file. My goal is eventually to learn how to manipulate and extrapolate data.

1. IDE Thonny
2. Py Version 3.6.4
3. XLDR installed via PIP

**CMD Prompt for PIP**

```
C:\Users\adtoes>pip install xlrd 
Requirement already satisfied: xlrd in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
```

**CODE:**

```
import xlrd
file_location = "D:/SampleData/Sampledata.xlsx"
work = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
```

**Console output for Thonny**

```
Python 3.6.4
>>> import xlrd
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlrd'
```

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: -> `already satisfied: xlrd in c:\python27` You have to install it for python 3. Try `python3 -m pip install --user xlrd`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why i still can't use the NumPy module even the terminal says "requirement already satisfied"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143533/why-i-still-cant-use-the-numpy-module-even-the-terminal-says-requirement-alrea)

Answer (score 4):

You're installing the package in `Python 2` and trying to import it from `Python 3`

Try this:

```
python2
>>> import xlrd
```

Comment: so aside from running py -2 or py -3 in cli is there a way to set it in thonny? I think it's only compatible with py3.

i opened it in Spyder IDE and it worked right away..


runfile('D:/crunch.py', wdir='D:')
worked?

Comment: I've never worked with that editor, but I think that there is only a python3 version of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Thonny's default settings, then it uses a built-in Python 3 virtual environment. To install stuff into this environment use "Tools => Manage packages ..." or "Tools => Open System shell ...".

Comment: This solved my Thonny issue as well for xlrd, scipy.